# CDI Activate producer packaged in jar

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, cdi

i have a producer, i want to put it in a jar, so that my diff war files can refer the same implementation

```
public class LogFactory {

  @Produces
  public Logger createLogger(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
    return Logger.getLogger(injectionPoint.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getName());
  }
}
```

but it turns now, glassfish (3.0.1) can not auto discover the producer method

how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure but is the JAR CDI enabled (i.e. does it have a `beans.xml`)?

Comment: i got it, went back to read the spec, turns out i need to put the beans.xml inside the meta-inf